# Deploy my ubuntu azure VM to work from HTTP

Tags: azure, ubuntu

I did a VM on ubuntu 16.04 and installed some open source on it
I added inbound rules to security group for allowing http but it still not working and the web page is not displayed
I found some sites talking about End Points but I couldn't reach them and I don't know if they differ from inbound rules 
This is the web site 52.168.20.27
How can I solve it?

Comment: install and use links to see if you can reach it from inside the VM.

Comment: How can I reach it from inside the VM? It is ubuntu machine, how can I access the local host from inside the machine?

Comment: use links http://localhost. You can also try nmap localhost to check if port 80 is open.

Comment: port 80 is closed

Comment: then its not azure. its your web server. check configuration and ubuntu firewall if applicable.

Comment: This is probably best for SuperUser or ServerFault. You're asking some basic VM / network configuration questions. Not programming-related, and off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: The problem is solved after openning the port, Thanks Bruno

Answer (score 0):

It was a closed port problem and it is solved after opening the port

Comment: If possible, please mark it as an answer. It will help more people.